# Migrate LVM with MDADM underneath

Tags: lvm, mdadm, migration

Ok, so this has been fun to diagnose but I've learned a bit about LVM and brushed up on my MDADM, so overall not a bad day!

What I'm trying to accomplish is migrate 2 external enclosures with multiple 2 devices MDADM RAID1 mirros setup underneath of a giant LVM.

Example:

```
sda + sdb = 2TB in RAID1 with mdadm = /dev/md1
sdc + sdd = 2TB in RAID1 with mdadm = /dev/md2

VolGroup = /dev/md1 /dev/md2
Logical Volume = 100% of Available Space in VG
```

I have tested without mdadm and been successful with simply using the following:

Old Server:

```
umount vggroup
vgchange -a n vggroup
vgexport vggroup
```

New Server:

```
pvscan
vgimport vggroup
vgchange -a n vggroup
```

But with the underlying mdadm I just get nothing with pvscan... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Durp, the new server didn't have MDADM installed. Once I installed the drivers, pvscan saw the Volume Group. Ugh.. although this was my fault and dumb, I am not a fan of LVM + MDADM + External Enclosures!

Update:

Also after install mdadm, I used the following (before pvscan, so I can't be sure!), not sure if thats what helped as well, but I'm done testing this for now!

```
sudo mdadm --assemble --scan
```